# @Transactional attribute timout doesn't work with attribute readOnly=true

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) we know, that

> Timeout: How long this transaction runs before timing out and being
>   rolled back automatically by the underlying transaction
>   infrastructure.

I have a code:

```
@Override
@Transactional(timeout = 2) // 2 seconds
public void someMethod() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Starting to sleep");
    Thread.sleep(4000L); // 4 seconds
    System.out.println("After sleeping");
    someRepository.save(myEntity);
}
```

Console output:

```
Starting to sleep
After sleeping
Hibernate: 
    insert 
...
transaction timeout expired; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: transaction timeout expired
```

`TransactionException` in this case is expected result.

But if i add readOnly attribute `@Transactional(readOnly = true, timeout = 2)`, TransactionException not thrown, and console output is:

```
Starting to sleep
After sleeping
```

As you see, without any exceptions there is no any inserts into DB because of readOnly=true. But where is TransactionException?

OK, I have one assumption. Maybe because of `readOnly = true` we have nothing to rollback. Am I right? Could you provide some proof of this assumption? Or, maybe you have another explanation?

I use:
Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE

MySql 5.5

Hibernate 5.4.8

Comment: read [this](https://github.com/AnghelLeonard/Hibernate-SpringBoot/tree/master/HibernateSpringBootTransactionTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you are confusing:

1. **timeout** in hibernate is applied from the moment you request the action from the database.
2. **Thread.sleep (4000L)** pauses for 4 seconds but in the application.

So if you want to see the use of the timeout you can add a query that takes more than 2 seconds in the process that is going to perform the action, since as you really understand those 4 seconds of sleep it is not taken into account because hibernate understands the rule of 2 seconds you added from the moment hibernate calls your insert.